# is it possible to divide shapekey to small ranges?

Tags: unity, shape-keys

i want to move iris on eye surface ( eye shape is mostly similar to oval not sphere ) and i want to do it
with shapekey
[image]

[image]

[image]

the problem is , when shapekey value changes , it cross other surface of mesh ,
is it possible to split shapekey value to smaller part and define a deform pattern for each parts,
for example from 0 to 0.1 shape deform like x , from 0.1 to 0.3 shape deform like y and... .

i want to export my model to unity , in unity shapekeys works with no problem , but modifiers like shrinkwarp not . or can anyone suggest another way for moving iris on eye that works with no problem in unity engine?

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer
best way is  add iris texture on eyeball (shrikwrap modifier not working in unity)
then  import model in to unity  , in unity add texture to eyeball material ,
for moving the iris must offset the texture from inspector and for eye movements must make animation from windows->animation->animation
[image]

making shapekey for iris is not a good idea.